# Using CSS to circular crop an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have used border radius to cut square iframe to circular (using earth2 class with border-radius:50%) but it still has black border remaining around earth. I want to crop off to show only earth. My code is below, what changes can I make to crop that black background too?

My current preview is here:

[image: My current preview is here]

My code is:

```
<style> 
.main_content {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.earth2{
    border-radius:50%;
    border-width:267px;
}

.earth {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border-radius:50%;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  opacity:0.8;
}
</style>

<div class="main_content">
    <div class="graph" id="canvas-holder" style="width:100%">
    <canvas id="chart-area" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    </div>

<div class="earth">
    <iframe class="earth2" src="https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/gltf_embed/2393" width="400px" height="400px" frameborder="0" >
    </iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply border 0px in order to make the border disappear to the div "earth"